# Java JList reporting incorrect index when using a KeyListener

Tags: java, keylistener

I would like to understand why the printed list index for this JLIST Object gets out of sync with the highlighted line when KeyPressedListener fires following up and down key press events, and how I might resolve the issue

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class ListTest
{

    private JFrame frame;
    private String[] values = new String[] {"Line 0", "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"};

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ListTest window = new ListTest();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public ListTest()
    {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 136, 153);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(values);
        frame.getContentPane().add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);
        list.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0){}
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0){}
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                int code = e.getKeyCode();

                switch( code ) 
                { 
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    System.out.println("UP " + list.getSelectedIndex());
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    System.out.println("DOWN " + list.getSelectedIndex());
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This situation may be of academic interest, but I feel the need to point out that the correct way to listen for changes to a JList’s selection is with [addListSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#addListSelectionListener-javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener-), since obviously the arrow keys aren’t the only way to change the selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `keyPressed` event will return the previous selection.

just get the output from `keyReleased` event and you'll be fine.

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0){
            int code = arg0.getKeyCode();

            switch( code ) 
            { 
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                System.out.println("UP " + list.getSelectedIndex());
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                System.out.println("DOWN " + list.getSelectedIndex());
                break;
            }
        }
```

Here's a better explanation of keyevents

> keyPressed(): when the key goes down
>
> keyReleased(): when the key comes up
>
> keyTyped(): when the unicode character represented by this key is sent
> by the keyboard to system input.

The selection of an item in `JList` happens when the key comes up. When `keyReleased():` is fired the next item in `JList` will already be selected. But `keyPressed():` event fires before the selection happens.

Comment: Thankyou so much. As usual, the answer was staring me in the face; I just couldn't see it :-)

Comment: You're very welcome. Edited with a better explanation.